# .htaccess REDIRECT_LOOP prevents PHP_SELF from executing functions properly

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The following redirect is preventing a form with php_self from running functions on the same page properly. 
I was having trouble removing the trailing slash for some reason on this server so I went this route. Found it interesting! The page refreshes but runs no code. Changing the page to prevent redirect goes back to working. Any thoughts?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

DirectorySlash Off

RewriteRule ^bio$ /bio/index.php [L,E=LOOP:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^bio/$ /bio [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_LOOP} !1
RewriteRule ^bio/index.php$ /bio [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# remove slash if not directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: Is `/bio` a directory?

Comment: Yes, it is. As mentioned I couldn't removing trailing slash so I went this route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep `DirectorySlash` off if you don't want `/` at the end of a directory:

```
DirectorySlash off

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/index$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=302,L]

# route to bio/index.php if request is /bio
RewriteRule ^bio$ bio/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]
```

Comment: I've tested properly. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Just look around the web and you will find the meaning of first rule with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST` condition which ignores all rules for `POST` requests. You have either other .htaccess or your code behaving unexpectedly for you.

Comment: I do have other .htaccess directives but nothing that is interfering. When I add RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST it causes 500 error -- which is why the page is blank

Comment: And did you tell my anywhere about this 500 error before? How do you expect to get help if you don't provide enough information. Check your Apache error.log to see why 500 is showing up.

Comment: I'm getting 'PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method' which is the function being called in /bio/index.php. Looks like it's throwing off the include path.

Comment: Well that is your PHP code error that you need to figure out, it is not related to new rewrite rule.

Comment: It is related, but I get what you are saying.